# when i try to join meshes it replaces the textures

Tags: mesh, uv

for starters i am new to blender i followed the following turtorial: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLhiuav2SCuvd5eAOb3Ct1eovFAlgv-iwe

i used the same versions that are mentioned in the start of the turtorial. in part 9 you need to combine the mesh but when i do that almost the hole model starts using the hair textures.

i looked it up on google but most people say to make sure the uvmaps are called the same, but when i checked they where already named the same.

[image: before join]
[image: after join]

after trying to add them one by one i had discoverd that there are 2 parts that cause the problem
-cf_hair_f106_00.002
-Horns

[image: after 1by1]
[image: after adding the horns]

Comment: hello, maybe share your file (pack all your images before saving: File > External Data > Pack All Into .blend) https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots cant upload using pasteall the file is 95mb so i used mega [link](https://mega.nz/file/fQBwkThA#JjgGyN5RPiv9kAz_Wr6YKrOHppR08V-Au5C-KEPhtRo)